# How do I create a rails simple_form with variable input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, simple-form

I have a `PurchaseOrder` Model that `has_many` `Item`s. The form for `PurchaseOrder` needs variable input fields that will also save `Items`, where clicking the `Add` button will increase the fields in the page.

Here's what it will look like:

[image]

In order to achieve this:

How do I create a simple_form that will post the result of these multiple fields as an array to my existing `PurchaseOrder`controller where I can process and add these records?

Bonus: how would I handle this via Cucumber?

**Edit:** Why would you downvote a self contained question? [Leave comments to explain when you downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?newreg=ca79bf2f6889489195d7791c63508ea7), please.

Comment: @Fallenhero nothing, honestly, the documentation on simple_from doesn't contain this usecase. I'm considering dropping into regular form helpers and attaching these as additional fields and processing them on my own.

But I still have no idea how to approach this with Cucumber.

Comment: Are you trying to add multiple items to a single purchase order or add more fields like colour and manufacturer to the items in the purchase order?

Comment: @user3402754 adding multiple line items to the purchase order.

Comment: Thanks to a slack conversation I had, i was pointed to: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon which does exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: You can use Cocoon gem for that here is the link https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`simple_fields_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#simple-fields-for) from [`simple_form` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). This allows you to work with attributes of associated models.

If you want to add new associated models via `Add new` button you need to create a new row. There is no code in pure `simple_form` that will help you with that. I found [gem `cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). It looks like it's what you're looking for. You can take a look how it's implemented there and make your own light solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) as your nested forms for creating multiple fields.